# Почему не работает код программа?

Tags: c

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
int n;
scanf("%i", &n);
int* (M) = (int*)malloc(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%i", (M + i));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%i ", *M + i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int* (M) = (int*)malloc(n);
```

замените на

```
int* M = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

а

```
printf("%i ", *M + i);
```

на

```
printf("%i ", *(M + i));
```

https://ideone.com/UQa6gc

Comment: Всё равно не работает.

Comment: Я еще не все успел написать :) Смотрите теперь.

Comment: Разве есть разница между *(M+i) и *M+i. Если да, то в чём?

Comment: @Anonymous неправильное инкрементирование при использовании *M+i

Comment: @Anonymous `*(M+i)` равно `M[i]` (i-ый элемент массива), а `*M+i` равно `(*M) + i` и равно `M[0] + i` (первый элемент массива + i).

Comment: Разыменование имеет бОльший приоритет. `*M+i` - это `(*M) + i`, а не `*(M+i)`

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в размер выделения памяти sizeof() тк размер считается по байтам.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
int n;
scanf("%i", &n);
int* (M) = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%i", (M + i));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%i ", *(M + i));
}
```

Попробуйте ещё добавить `return 0;` в конце программы, если компилятор просит

Comment: Думаю для вывода нужно *(M + i)

Comment: @Да, тоже, исправлю

Comment: Не помогло, так и не запустилась.

Comment: @Anonymous А какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Неправильно выводит массив

Comment: @Anonymous думаю проблема в том, что Вы вводите. Между вводимыми числами могут быть только пробелы, символы табуляции или переход на новую строку